# Cannot change icon and UI themes after disabling GTK+ on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, 17.10

I'm having a problem changing themes.

In GNOME Tweak Tool I have disabled GTK+!

- can anyone help me enable it?
- over GTK+ **Ambiance** theme is little triangle and it indicates that this function is disabled.

[image: tweak tool]

Can anyone help me install a different theme?

Comment: Where is the little triangle?

Comment: what do you mean by not being able to change icons? you talk about gtk themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved...
I just reinstall gnome tool and refresh-d sesion
- nothing spcial :D

Comment: after reinstalling the gnome tweak tool you mean? and then what? you have been able to change the Ambiance theme?